# How to use a class defined within a class?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to define a class within a class. I am not trying to solve a real world problem with this. I am simply trying to learn Python with this code.

```
class Foo:
    class Bar:
        def __init__(self):
            self.x = 'Bar'

    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 'Foo'
        self.bar = Bar()

    def print(self):
        print('self.x:', self.x)
        print('self.bar.x:', self.bar.x)

foo = Foo()
foo.print()
```

When I try to execute this code, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "demo.py", line 14, in <module>
    foo = Foo()
  File "demo.py", line 8, in __init__
    self.bar = Bar()
NameError: name 'Bar' is not defined
```

What went wrong? When we can define and use functions defined within a function, why not the same for classes? Am I making a mistake in using `Bar` class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Foo.Bar()` instead, because `Bar` is not a global name.

Answer (score 3):

You need to access `Bar` through `Foo` (`Bar` is not defined in module level)

Replace following line:

```
self.bar = Bar()
```

with:

```
self.bar = Foo.Bar()
```

or

```
self.bar = self.Bar()
```

According to [Class definition](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#class-definitions):

> The
>   class’s suite is then executed in a new execution frame (see section
>   [Naming and binding](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#naming)), using a newly created local namespace and the
>   original global namespace. (Usually, the suite contains only function
>   definitions.) *When the class’s suite finishes execution, **its execution
>   frame is discarded** but its local namespace is saved.* A class
>   object is then created using the inheritance list for the base classes
>   and the saved local namespace for the attribute dictionary. The class
>   name is bound to this class object in the original local namespace.